# Adding letters to the top of a game board printed with nested for loops

Tags: java

I created a class with the intention of using it to print an 8 by 8 game board to the screen for othello an othello game. I have the game board printing with letters down the side, however I can't figure out in my head how print letters above the top line of the board.

Here's the class code so far:

```
public class CreateBoard {
public char[][] board;

public CreateBoard(){
    board = new char[8][8];

}

public void printBoard(){

    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < board.length; j++){
            board[i][j] = '-';  
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
        System.out.println();
        for(int j = 0; j < board.length; j++){
            if(j == 0){
                System.out.print(i + 1);
                System.out.print("| ");
            }
            System.out.print(board[i][j] + " | ");  
        }
    }
}
```

So, what would be the correct way to implement numbers above the top row? Thanks in advance.

Here's how the output currently is:

[image]

Here's how i'd like it to look:

[image]

Comment: _with letters down the side_ what did you mean by this? Can you show us what you get and what you expect.

Comment: Sorry, I mean numbers. You know on a gameboard you generally have letters on top and numbers down the right side so someone can coordinates of squares.

I have the numbers down the left side but don't know how to print the letters at the top.

Comment: Edit your question and Can you show us a sample output of how it is and how it should be.

Comment: Hints: https://ideone.com/BOKyJE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a for loop to print the characters before you print the board.

```
public void printBoard(){

System.out.print("  ");//beginning 2 spaces
for(int i = 0; i < board.length; ++i)
   System.out.print(" " + (char)(i + 'A') +" ");//print letters seperately.

for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < board.length; j++){
        board[i][j] = '-';  
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
    System.out.println();
    for(int j = 0; j < board.length; j++){
        if(j == 0){
            System.out.print(i + 1);
            System.out.print("| ");
        }
        System.out.print(board[i][j] + " | ");  
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh I thought you were looking for the replacement of the character in the box and update it. Anyway the board display changes are very well suggested according to the requirement.

```
public class CreateBoard {
    public char[][] board;

    public CreateBoard() {
        board = new char[8][8];
    }

    public void printBoard() {
        System.out.print("  ");
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            char hor = (char)(i+65);
            System.out.print(hor + " ");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
                board[i][j] = '-';
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
                if (j == 0) {
                    System.out.print(i + 1);
                    System.out.print("|");
                }
                System.out.print(board[i][j] + "|");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CreateBoard cb = new CreateBoard();

        //Initial board
        cb.printBoard();

        //During Game
//        while(<end game condition>){
//            <input from user> <update the board>
//                    board[i][j] = <input>
//                    cb.printBoard();
//        }

        //End Game
        cb.printBoard();
        System.out.println("Thanx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this too :)